# How to check if string contains an image?

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to figure out a way to check whether a string, in this case a tweet extracted by the tweepy module includes an image or attachment.

so far, I can only come up with the following:

```
images = 0

if "https://" in tweet.text:
    images += 1
```

which would give me a total count of image use per user, as this code is inserted in a for loop looping over all relevant users. Is there a more comprehensive way to do this?

Example of a tweet.text:

'RT @epensa: @CVSHealth @CVS_Extra team opening first CVS pharmacy inside Target. @HWheelerCVS @ndegreve https://twitter.com/epensa/status/694924980526673920/photo/1'

https://twitter.com/epensa/status/694924980526673920/photo/1 is the image in this case. In actuality, the URL is shortened by twitter.

So, all attachments, whether they are links or images, start with "https://", which is why I thought it to be the easiest way.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tweepy module, but you could use the `str.startswith()`, `str.endswith('.png')` (maybe?); or even the `re` module to match a structure for an image such as checking for `.png` endings etc..

Comment: you should post an example of `tweet.text`, that could help … currently, I fear your code is only filtering on links (over https).